# How to bind booleans in JTable with JGoodies

Tags: java, swing, binding, jtable, jgoodies

I have seven `boolean` values in a column of a `JTable` that I want to bind to my bean.

How do I bind them?

All the `JTable` binding examples out there focus on binding the table selection, but I only care about what the values of those `booleans` are.

Comment: don't quite understand - those booleans are on different beans (aka: rows)? If so, bind to the bean/s directly ...

Comment: do you mean seven different boolean values in a row or in a column. If its in a row, you can define a bean with seven boolean attribute and bind each attribute to each column.If its column, i am not sure what it means. Basic thing is each row would represent a bean. So seven different boolean values on column means seven different beans  .

Comment: JTables store values as Object so, regardless of being boolean values you can bind them the same way you bind any other value type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own data model. I give you simplified example that shows idea of usage. Take a look at getColumnClass method.

Usage: table.setModel(new DataModel(myData));

```
class DataModel extends AbstractTableModel
{


    public DataModel(Object yourData){
         //some code here
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return yourData.rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return yourData.colums;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        if (col == myBooleanColumn) {
            return Boolean.class;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
    {
        return col >= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        return yourData.get(rowIndex,columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {           

    yourData.set(aValue,row,col)    

        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);  
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.